# How to detect distance using an image (similar to EasyMeasure app)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am developing an autonomous robot using an iPhone. I want it to analyze images from its camera to determine its distance to objects.
I know it is possible to detect distance using a single, regular camera because there is an app in the app store called EasyMeasure that detects the distance from the phone to the object using only the rear camera.
So my question is: a) what algorithm can achieve this? b) are there any open source libraries out there that do this?

Thank you.

Comment: A precise measurement is not necessary. All I'm looking for is a rough estimate of distance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without additional scale information about the scene. The app you mention is rubbish. Sorry.

Comment: But the app does  give a rough estimate of distance, which is all I want, so should be possible for my purposes. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "additional scale information" please?

Comment: Take a picture of, say, a car. How can the camera tell if it's looking at a real human-sized car, rather than a toy the size of a matchbox? Answer: it can't, unless you tell your algorithm. BTW, this is the idea behind the use of miniature models in movie special effects. For a good survey of what is and isn't possible in single-view metrology, look up Antonio Criminisi's old PhD thesis and paper.

A separate case is the one in which the subject is close enough that significant depth signal can be had from the lens focus. Look up depth-from-defocus.